# Liferay custom entity caching

Tags: caching, liferay, ehcache

I am using `liferay 6.1` version.

I have created custom entities for portlet using service builder. I want to cache that custom entities.

I have set following properties in my **portal-ext.properties** to enable cache.

```
ehcache.statistics.enabled=true
value.object.entity.cache.enabled=true
value.object.finder.cache.enabled=true

velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled=true
layout.template.cache.enabled=true

net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName=/custom_cache/hibernate-clustered.xml

log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=DEBUG
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.config=DEBUG 
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.distribution=DEBUG
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.code=DEBUG
```

I created **ehcache.xml** file to override the **ehcache-failsafe.xml** to configure my custom entities so that it can enable for caching.

my **ehcache.xml** file is in my classpath **[classpath:liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes]**.

```
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache"/>

<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        />

<cache
    eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    name="com.pr.test.model.impl.StudentImpl"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="600"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    statistics="true"
    copyOnRead="true"
    copyOnWrite="true"
    clearOnFlush="true"
    transactionalMode="off"
    />
```

Also create **hibernate-clustered.xml** file under src path **[/docroot/WEB-INF/src]** which is same as my **ehcache.xml** file.

since I am using service builder, cache-enable="true" is enough to cache the entities?

I use `Jconsole` to monitor the cache hits, But what the problem is the percentage for cache Misses is more than cache hits. Below is my statistics for caching :

[image: cashing statistics![][1]]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caching is enabled by default for services built using liferay service builder.

I believe none of the steps mentioned above are required as cache is default enabled.

Below properties are set to true in default portal.properties and applies to all entities, not just for custom entities.

```
value.object.entity.cache.enabled=true
value.object.finder.cache.enabled=true
```

You can open *PersistenceImpl.java class for your custom entities to observe the caching code. Debugging this class could give you details on why its not hitting cache.

For example, calling API with cache off argument won't hit cache.

Comment: But above screenshot  saw some figure about `cache hits` . If it calling API with cache off argument then why this possible ?

Comment: "cache off argument" is mentioned as just one example scenario mentioned. Can't comment more on reasons as I do not have information about API usage. But debugging inside your *PersistenceImpl class should reveal.

Comment: Ok. What about 'hibernate' level caching ? As I see the property `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true` this means that second level caching enable by default in liferay ?

Comment: Yes, hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache set to true by default. If you are using liferay CE, you can download liferay sources and find all the default properties in portal.properties file.

Comment: Yes , I know that. But for that may I need to configure other files or properties? And other question is : All level caching is done by default in liferay ?

Comment: Yes, all levels of caching enabled by default in liferay. No need of any custom configuration unless you want to turn off caching intentionally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75095/discussion-between-ckpatel-and-haris).